# Why use $.data instead of assigning properties to "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-plugins, jquery-data

I noticed a lot of jQuery plugin developers use the $.data function to store the state of some type of action.

```
$.data(this, 'playing', true);
```

instead of just assigning a property to the plugin object instance:

```
this.playing = true;
```

What's the deal here? Are there some benefits on using $.data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), it avoids memory leaks with circular references.

Also, `.data()` does not conflict with existing methods and properties of the `HTMLElement`, being more future proof.

---

By future proof, I mean, a simple example would be storing the play state of an `audio`/`video` element in its `playing` property, your code works and all is fine. Then tomorrow, the WHATWG decides to add a `playing` property to the [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) DOM interface and boom! Your code breaks or has unexpected side effects.

This is of course just a dumb example to illustrate the possibility for future conflicts, in the use case above you'd normally just read the `paused` property of the element.

Another example would be setting the `value` property -- you test it with a `span` and it works fine, then you ship the code and another developer tries to call the plugin on an input element, it will conflict with the `value` of the input. This kind of problem is easily avoided with `$.data`.

Talking in the general sense of storing metadata in a custom property of a DOM element, there is always a small probability of future conflict. Even though the odds are often very low, it is nice to feel more future proof and have one less thing to worry about.